# How to replace column values using replace() method while using dictionary?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

While replacing values of a column in a df using replace method how can we make use of the dictionary to do the same.I am having problems with the syntax.

```
   person = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "Bill Chambers", 0, [100]),
    (1, "Matei Zaharia", 1, [500, 250, 100]),
    (2, "Michael Armbrust", 1, [250, 100]),
    (1,'Adam',4,[200])])\
    .toDF("id", "name", "graduate_program", "spark_status")

diz={'Bill Chambers':'ABC','Adam':'DEF'}

I saw that the syntax is:
person.replace(diz,1,'name')
```

What is the significance of 1 here in the arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I encourage you to check pyspark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame) and search for `replace(to_replace, value=<no value>, subset=None)` function definition.

You are passing a dictionary `diz` with key/value pairs, and because of that value `1` will be ignored in your case, thus, you will get the following result:

```
>>> person.replace(diz,1,'name').show()
+---+----------------+----------------+---------------+
| id|            name|graduate_program|   spark_status|
+---+----------------+----------------+---------------+
|  0|             ABC|               0|          [100]|
|  1|   Matei Zaharia|               1|[500, 250, 100]|
|  2|Michael Armbrust|               1|     [250, 100]|
|  1|             DEF|               4|          [200]|
+---+----------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Note in your usage only column `name` that you specified as `subset` will be affected, and you can clearly see that your dictionary `key/value` pairs have been used as `to_replace/value`.

Now if you want to test how value argument should work, check this example:

```
>>> person.replace(['Adam', 'Bill Chambers'],['Bob', 'Omar'],'name').show()
+---+----------------+----------------+---------------+
| id|            name|graduate_program|   spark_status|
+---+----------------+----------------+---------------+
|  0|            Omar|               0|          [100]|
|  1|   Matei Zaharia|               1|[500, 250, 100]|
|  2|Michael Armbrust|               1|     [250, 100]|
|  1|             Bob|               4|          [200]|
+---+----------------+----------------+---------------+
```

**Note** if you want to specify another list of to_replace/value for two columns, check the following usage of `dataframe.replace()`:

```
>>> person.replace([1, 0],[9, 5],['id', 'graduate_program']).show()
+---+----------------+----------------+---------------+
| id|            name|graduate_program|   spark_status|
+---+----------------+----------------+---------------+
|  5|   Bill Chambers|               5|          [100]|
|  9|   Matei Zaharia|               9|[500, 250, 100]|
|  2|Michael Armbrust|               9|     [250, 100]|
|  9|            Adam|               4|          [200]|
+---+----------------+----------------+---------------+
```

In the previous example we targeted two same value typed (int) columns `[id, graduate_program]`, and forced all ones to be replaced with 9, and all zeros to be replaced with 5.

I hope this answers your question

Comment: What if I want to use dictionary to replace values for only the 'id' column?

Comment: Hey Mathers25, yes you can still use dictionary for replacing integers in columns, but the rule is you cannot mix types. So if you want to replace integers in column `id`, you can define the dictionary with integer `keys/values` as follow `diz={0:6,1:8}` and then run `person.replace(diz,1,'id').show()`, note that when you use dictionary, the `value` argument will be neglected.

Still you cannot define `diz={0:6,'Adam':'Bob'}` and then target multiple columns with different types `person.replace(diz,1,['id', 'name']).show()`, as this will generate an error (Mixed Type Replacement).

Comment: So the summary is, you can only replace one type at a time for multiple columns using `dataframe.replace()`